# Compiling V8 JavaScript engine faster

Tags: v8

I have a project where I'm using the V8 JavaScript engine from Google. I also use Travis CI to build and deploy my project. The build often exceeds the maximum time limit (~45 min) and fails because of this. I have done the following to speed up the compile time for V8 (which made some difference):

- Don't build tests
- Disabled support for i18n

How could I speed up the compile time for V8 even more?

Comment: Can't you just use it as a library? Are you continually modifying it so you have to rebuild it?

Comment: I'm just using it as a library. How can I get the precompiled libs for v8? (I'm compiling for os x).

Comment: If you have the source, can't you create libraries yourself? Compile them to a library beforehand, and include them in your project instead?
I don't program C++, so I have no clue to create them, but google tells me https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library#Creating_static_libraries_in_C.2FC.2B.2B -- sorry I can't help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the built-in [caching features](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/) in Travis CI. Time to compile went down from 45 min to 13 min. Happy! Thanks to the comments that pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Care to explain exactly how you did it?

Answer (score 1):

I use V8 binary package from a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~pinepain/+archive/ubuntu/libv8-5.4). in my [.travis.yml](https://github.com/pmed/v8pp/blob/master/.travis.yml) file. It looks like this:

```
before_install:
  - sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pinepain/libv8-5.2 -y
  - sudo apt-get update -q
  - sudo apt-get install libv8-dev -y
```

Comment: That looks really good! I want v8 version 4.9.385.33, can't find it there.

Comment: You can also see at https://github.com/pmed/v8pp/blob/master/build-v8.sh script. I used it before to build only V8 libraries on Travis, but haven't touch that script since switching to PPA.